# How to bind a surface object to a 2D pitched array?

Tags: c++, cuda, surface

I can bind a surface object to a CUDA array, but failed to bind it to a 2D pitched array.

Below is a self-contained example: (please ignore other resource management issues)

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

void throw_on_error(cudaError_t ec)
{
    if (ec)
        throw std::runtime_error(cudaGetErrorString(ec));
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        char* p;
        std::size_t stride;
        throw_on_error(cudaMallocPitch(&p, &stride, 8, 8));
        cudaSurfaceObject_t s;
        cudaResourceDesc rd = {};
        rd.resType = cudaResourceTypePitch2D;
        auto& data = rd.res.pitch2D;
        data.devPtr = p;
        data.pitchInBytes = stride;
        data.width = 8;
        data.height = 8;
        data.desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<char>();
        throw_on_error(cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&s, &rd));
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It prints `invalid argument`, what's wrong here?

Compute Capability: 3.0

Comment: Your `self-contained example` does not compile

Comment: It requires you have CUDA SDK installed.

Comment: It also requires c++11 feature support (e.g. `auto`) which may be why pQB made the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to [the API documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__SURFACE__OBJECT.html#group__CUDART__SURFACE__OBJECT_1gf132bf8075f8da3a3c5d92d07a93730d):

> cudaResourceDesc::resType must be cudaResourceTypeArray and cudaResourceDesc::res::array::array must be set to a valid CUDA array handle.

You cannot use this:

```
    rd.resType = cudaResourceTypePitch2D;
```

You must use a valid `cudaArray` type.

You can refer to the [cuda samples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#bindless-texture) (e.g. bindless texture) for an example of proper surface object setup.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow got the impression from some book that I can bind a surface to a pitched array. Anyway, the API of `cudaCreateSurfaceObject` is really misguiding, it should just take a `cudaArray_t` if it can only accept `cudaArray_t`.